# RecyclerView: Inconsistency detected when update grouped items by PagedListAdapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, indexoutofboundsexception

I using `android.arch.paging.PagedListAdapter <Item, RecyclerView.ViewHolder>` and **Room DB** as data source for show items in `RecyclerView`.

Each item has date day. I also group elements by this date in `override fun onCurrentListChanged(currentList: PagedList<Item>?).` 
Grouping occurs by dividing into two lists (Items and Dates) with fake positions. Total count is sum items count and dates count.

My problem is an `IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected` from `RecyclerView` when refresh or load next items.

Possible solutions: 1 - refuse to separate items (not suitable for my task). 2 - Use `notifyDataSetChanged()` after submit items (but disappear animation and appear blink update viewHolders).

Can anyone help?

```
private var fakePositionDates: Map<Int, Date> = emptyMap()
private var fakePositionTaskPositions: Map<Int, Int> = emptyMap()

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return fakePositionTaskPositions.size + fakePositionDates.size
}

override fun submitList(pagedList: PagedList<Task>?) {
    super.submitList(pagedList)
}

override fun onCurrentListChanged(currentList: PagedList<Task>?) {
    val groupTasksPositions = currentList?.asIterable()
            ?.mapIndexed { index, task ->
                Pair(index, task.publishDate)
            }
            ?.groupBy { it.second }
            ?.mapValues {
                it.value.map { it.first }
            }
            ?.toSortedMap(Comparator { o1, o2 ->
                o2.compareTo(o1)
            })
            ?: sortedMapOf()

    val fakePositionDates = mutableMapOf<Int, Date>()
    val fakePositionTaskPositions = mutableMapOf<Int, Int>()
    var fakePosition = 0

    groupTasksPositions.forEach { date, realPositions ->
        fakePositionDates[fakePosition] = date
        fakePosition += 1
        realPositions.forEach {
            fakePositionTaskPositions[fakePosition] = it
            fakePosition += 1
        }
    }

    this.fakePositionTaskPositions = fakePositionTaskPositions
    this.fakePositionDates = fakePositionDates
}
```

Comment: please provide code here. Inconsistency detected this error raise when you are using recyclerview on another thread or you are not using notifydatasetchanged() properly

Comment: added my code. SubmitList executed from mainThread

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `adapter.submitList(null)` and `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged` in your activity or fragment before you call view model function to refresh your recyclerview